# A div between 2 divs width 100%

Tags: css, html

On my page I have div structure like this.

-On body there are 2 divs. First 20% width, second 80% width.
-In first div there are 3 divs alongside. First floats left: 11px width, Third floats right: 22px width. I wanna place 2nd div between 1st and 3rd divs covers 100% of the remaining width.

I cannot make the 2nd div like this. How can I do it?

Comment: post your markup and styles over here

Comment: Put you html and css over here so we can work on it

Comment: here is the example of my page. http://jsfiddle.net/KLJHV/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="firstdiv">
    <div class="first">1</div>
    <div class="third">3</div>
    <div class="second">2</div>
</div>
<div class="secdiv">80%</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.firstdiv{
    width:20%;
    float:left;
    background:red;
    }
    .secdiv{
     overflow:hidden;
     background:green;
    }

.first{
    float:left;
    width:11px;
    background:yellow;
}
.third{
    float:right;
    width:22px;
    background:pink;
}
.second{
    overflow:hidden;
    background:blue;
}
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SB7dn/4/)

Comment: It works! but what about the sequence of the div's?? it will be always confusing. Why we cant make it with correct ordering(1,2,3)???

Comment: @SVS yes we can create with order(1,2,3) with display:table-cell; but it's work till IE8. This solution works in older IE browsers also. In this i use a trick of overflow:hidden;

Comment: @sandeep but on placing the div in right order overflow:hidden didn't work. Why so??